# Can SpaceTime Jutsu users do time travel?

Tags: naruto

We know that Obito's Kamui, Tobirama/Minato's Flying Thundergod are SpaceTime jutsus. They are using the fourth dimension to go to any/marked places at will. As per physics & Theory of relativity, if you have mastered the fourth dimension you can do both Space AND Time travel. Why can't they do time travel when they can do space travel ?

Answer (score 3):

To time travel, one needs to be [faster than light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_travel#Via_faster-than-light_.28FTL.29_travel). While those ninjas use Time-Space Jutsu, none of them are faster than light.

**Obito**

Of the three, Obito is the slowest as his space-time jutsu (kamui) has some delay, proven by Kakashi's successfully landing attack on him before he managed to disappear.

**Senju Tobirama & Namikaze Minato**

Both are very fast. Minato can even teleport to one of his marked kunai. I'm not sure if Tobirama can also do that, I don't remember. But the point is, although they are incredibly fast, they are not faster than light. We can safely say this, because if they are faster than light, then Minato wouldn't have his arm ripped by Madara and Tobirama won't be pinned on the ground. They would have been able to avoid Madara's attacks if they are faster than light. Thus, they cannot time travel.

Other possible ways to time travel that I know is by the use of Wormhole, which doesn't exist in Naruto universe.

Comment: If you can do space travel, obviously you can do time travel. For example, use Kamui to teleport yourself to somewhere close to a Blackhole. Stay there for few minutes then return back to earth. You would've passed a few years. Gravity plays an important role here, check this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation

Comment: How exactly you teleport near black hole so that you are not too close to have your body ripped apart while still get the time dilation effect? Also, how are you suppose to stay alive being so near to a Black Hole where a lot of energies are? Don't forget that near a black hole, lots of energy are spinning, creating the accretion disk. I don't think anyone can survive such massive amount of energy

Comment: Though the gravitational pull is more near a blackhole, still there could be planets around with their own gravity like Planet earth. Their life span will be very less relatively. He can teleport himself to one of those planets and make a comeback. Narutopedia says, "By absorbing their own body into this distortion, the user can teleport to virtually any location they desire"  (http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kamui). I don't think its very difficult to create his own version of spacesuit.

Comment: You are forgetting the fact that Kamui has a time delay. The matter around the black hole moves very fast due to the acceleration from the black hole's gravity. Before he can use the jutsu, he'd die from the energies around him. Also, I think you underestimate the amount of energy around the black hole. Obito would need a  space suit that can withstand star-level energy and ultra-massive gravitational pull that'd rip his body to pieces.

Comment: I do agree that Kamui has time delay, but the delay happens only while moving In/Out of the dimension. So, that shouldn't be a problem. Let it take even 1 min to enter into the planet from the 4th dimension, that's fine. Second, I am not underestimating the gravitational pull of a black hole. and I am not saying he has to dive inside the black hole or orbit around it. He can move to a planet which has its own gravity and orbiting its own star which is closer to a black hole relative to the earth.

Comment: I think we are going off-topic, should we continue this? lol

Comment: @KaguyaOtsutsuki Move to Maid-Cafe chat room, then.